# jquery mouseover events

Tags: jquery

How could I keep this working constantly.  The mouseover works only once, but I'd like it to work at all times.

```
                  if (!self.options.overlapEventsSeparate) {
                    $(this).bind('mouseover.z-index', function() {
                        var $elem = $(this);
                        $.each(curGroup, function() {
                          $(this).css({'z-index': '1'});
                        });
                        $elem.css({'z-index': '3'});
                    });
                  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to include your markup and put it all in a fiddle.

Comment: Let's say there is 3 div's, and they are layered on top of each other slightly exposing top/left of it.  If i were to put my mouse over the middle div, I'd like the zindex to be higher than the z-index below it.  Should work if I have 3+ also.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want that the divs below the topmost one should retain their orders, but in case you just want to get a topmost, you just need to create a helper class with a **huge** `z-index` and permutate it throughout your divs... I'm pretty sure there is a better solution but what I can think about now is something like this:

```
$("div").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).siblings(".z-front").removeClass("z-front").end().addClass("z-front");
    });​
```

You can see the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rJUC6/3/

Comment: That's not going to do it.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you could increment the z-index.

js (using comments for brevity)

```
//initial
zIndexVal = 3;

//mouseover stuff
//z increases every time (: ensuring no matter where it is it's on top.
zindexVal++
//then set objects z
```

In *most* situations this works well.

Like This: http://jsfiddle.net/QBsde/

Comment: Can you help me tie that into the code I have above?  Would greatly appreciate it.